# SSIS - ole db source/destination - only retrieve rows from source server WHERE EXISTS in table destination server

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, etl

I am transfering 90 million rows from a source server to my staging area on the destination server.
And from the staging area I transfer 20 million further up the ETL process by doing an WHERE ID EXISTS in a table located on the destination server.

Since the table is *not* present on the source server and only in the destination server. Is it possible to filter when I pull the rows directly from the source server (so I only transfer 20 million rows from the source server to my destination server)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides creating a linked server on the Source Server. there are two pure SSIS approaches.

1. Create a temp staging table at the Destination server, copy all records from Source to this temp stage table, and use `where exists` filter.
2. On the Data Flow, create a Lookup transformation which for lookup set gets IDs from the table of the Destination Server. Then proceed with matched records only. For performance reason, you may use either Lookup in full cache or partial cache mode; only performance testing can tell which mode is better.

Hadi's recommendations with Linked Server are fine and will work. Pure SSIS approach has advantage that it does not bring any changes to the Source Server, all connection configuration is inside SSIS. In some cases it can be beneficial. Its disadvantage - performance can be worse that with Linked Server.

If needed to transfer as little rows from Source as possible, the most simple way is the Linked Server approach. Otherwise, one can create a table at Source Server (it even can be a global temp ## table created at SSIS package task) and copy filter IDs from the Destination server. The temp table should be a **global** with ##, since it will be filled at one task and used in subsequent tasks. Then filter records with `EXISTS` clause at the Source server.

Comment: Hi Fredipux, I suggested using Linked Server since lookups are not best practices when working with millions of rows. Concerning the staging table, I think that the main OP question is how to avoid staging tables.

Comment: Even if I recommend using staging tables :)

Comment: These methods do not help me since I still have to transfer all 90 million rows. The goal is to transfer as few rows as possible from source to destination. Would it be possible to create a temp table at the source, insert the lookup id's and then use that to filter before pulling the rows?

Comment: @tutu, added approach with temp table at the Source server

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by creating a linked server on the source machine. Linked servers allows to join tables on different instances:

- [How to create and configure a linked server in SQL Server Management Studio](https://www.sqlshack.com/how-to-create-and-configure-a-linked-server-in-sql-server-management-studio/)
- [Create Linked Servers (SQL Server Database Engine)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/create-linked-servers-sql-server-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: I've thought about using a linked server. Unfortunately that's not possible on the source server